# How to get the mean of a specific span of time

Tags: python, time, html, pandas, mean

I started learning two weeks ago and now I'm kind of stuck. I have 2 TimeSeries which look like this one:

```
2011-01-09 00:00:00+00:00    7.430126
2011-01-09 01:00:00+00:00    6.793855
2011-01-09 02:00:00+00:00    6.675949
2011-01-09 03:00:00+00:00    6.756636
2011-01-09 04:00:00+00:00    6.875174
2011-01-09 05:00:00+00:00    5.432611
2011-01-09 06:00:00+00:00    6.059197
2011-01-09 21:00:00+00:00    5.338928
2011-01-09 22:00:00+00:00    5.259672
2011-01-09 23:00:00+00:00    5.247196
2011-01-10 00:00:00+00:00    5.889274
2011-01-10 01:00:00+00:00    6.133871
2011-01-10 02:00:00+00:00    6.111958
2011-01-10 03:00:00+00:00    5.873732
2011-01-10 04:00:00+00:00    5.627684
2011-01-10 05:00:00+00:00    5.265644
2011-01-10 06:00:00+00:00    5.505559
2011-01-10 21:00:00+00:00    3.835050
2011-01-10 22:00:00+00:00    3.879653
2011-01-10 23:00:00+00:00    4.034543
2011-01-11 00:00:00+00:00    4.844272
2011-01-11 01:00:00+00:00    4.670967
2011-01-11 02:00:00+00:00    4.584164
2011-01-11 03:00:00+00:00    4.786821
```

This is a data of a measurement of wind speed and I want to compare it with model data. More specifically, I want to compare the wind speeds at night (21.00 - 6.00). So I defined a function:

```
def func(model, measure):
    return (model-measure).mean()
```

In addition, I created a loop over the data:

```
mean_night = []
start = 7
for a in night:
    mean_night.append(func(model, measure[start:(start+10)]))
    start = start+11
    if start>5378:
            break
```

The problem is that I lose my time index and that some data is missing (for example 1 day or 1 week), so I get in trouble reindexing it with a DateRange. In the end, it should look like this:

```
date    difference_means
2011-01-09    diff_1
2011-01-09    diff_2
```

and so on. I use pandas 0.7.1. Thanks for support! (and sorry for my bad English :P)

Comment: Just to make sure I follow - you want your output to be the timestamp for each of the night hours but to have the data be the distance of that measurement from the mean or how far it is from the previous row's value?

Comment: Why don't you create a class with fields `date`, `mean`?  Or even just store the info as a tuple; i.e. `mean_night.append((date, func(...)))`?  Then you don't worry about indexing.

Comment: @IamChuckB I want to find out what's the difference between the model data and the real values at each night from 2011-01-09 to 2012-06-30. My datas look like above and the problem is that I lose the Timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

pandas 0.8.1
For hourly sampled data:

```
In [57]: import pandas

In [58]: import numpy

In [59]: index = pandas.date_range(start='2011-01-09', periods=240, freq='H')

In [60]: s = pandas.Series(np.random.randn(len(index)), index)

In [61]: s_night = s[(s.index.hour >= 21) | (s.index.hour <= 6)]

In [62]: def day_or_night(dates):
   ....:     r = []
   ....:     for date in dates:
   ....:         if (date.hour >= 21) | (date.hour <= 6):
   ....:             d = datetime.datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day)
   ....:             if (date.hour <= 6):
   ....:                 d = d - pandas.offsets.Day()
   ....:             r.append(d)
   ....:         else:
   ....:             r.append('day')
   ....:     return r
   ....:

In [63]: s_night.groupby(day_or_night(s_night.index)).mean()
Out[63]:
2011-01-08    0.652095
2011-01-09    0.004129
2011-01-10    0.457892
2011-01-11   -0.078547
2011-01-12    0.008087
2011-01-13    0.043568
2011-01-14    0.505970
2011-01-15    0.150971
2011-01-16    0.107265
2011-01-17    0.117811
2011-01-18   -0.191193
```

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to 0.8.1 and take advantage of all the new timeseries functionality.
Please checkout http://pandas.pydata.org for documentation.

In the newest versions, checkout functions like `between_time` to filter within certain time ranges.

Comment: `between_time` does not handle day crossing, so it can not be used in this case. s.between_time('21:00', '06:00') returns an empty series.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that works:

```
hr = dr.map(lambda x: x.hour)
meantime = lambda x: x.replace(hour=0)

datra = pd.DateRange('2011/1/1', '2011/12/31', offset=pd.datetools.day)
rise = pd.TimeSeries(np.cos(((datra.map(lambda x: (x-datetime(x.year,1,1)).total_seconds() / 86400) + 10) / 183. * np.pi)) * -2. + 17., index=datra)
set = pd.TimeSeries(np.cos(((datra.map(lambda x: (x-datetime(x.year,1,1)).total_seconds() / 86400) + 10) / 183. * np.pi)) * 2.5 + 5., index=datra)

i=0
def bias_night(liste, group):
while (i<546):
    if (i<364):
        z = group[dr[hr>unter11[i]]].combine_first(group[dr[hr<auf11[i+1]]]).groupby(meantime).mean()
        liste.append(z[i])
    else:
        z = group[dr[hr>unter11[i-365]]].combine_first(group[dr[hr<auf11[i-365+1]]]).groupby(meantime).mean()
        liste.append(z[i])
    i = i+1
t = group[dr[hr>unter11[364]]].combine_first(group[dr[hr<auf11[0]]]).groupby(meantime).mean()
liste.insert(364, t[364])
```

liste is an empty list and group is one of my TimeSeries. In the end, i just have to subtract the resulting lists to get what I want.

```
2011-01-09   -1.179578
2011-01-10   -0.978171
2011-01-11   -0.335977
2011-01-12    0.080671
2011-01-13   -0.324661
2011-01-14    0.012359
2011-01-15   -0.549079
```